# What is a non binary adjacency Matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, symmetric-matrices, adjacency-matrix

I am going through the implementation of a graph convolutional neural network. I came across a non-binary adjacency matrix in the case of a directed graph.

The particular issue is discussed here in the following

https://github.com/tkipf/pygcn/issues/3

Can someone explain what a non-binary adjacency matrix looks like? How can an adjacency matrix have something other than 0 or 1?

Comment: Maybe in cases where there are [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)) or [parallel edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_edges)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some uses, the value of the [adjacency matrix](https://graph.subwiki.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) is the number of [parallel edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_edges) connecting the nodes.